# How to Split the td having colspan attr value into individual TD with the same value using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I need to split the td which is having colspan attr into each td's with the same value.

Here I have colspan="3", So i need to populate 3 TD's with the same value .

Here is my html

```
<tr style="height:15.0pt;"><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" class="dt-checkboxes" value="">
            <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td><td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_0_2" colspan="3">Seguros Generales</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_0_1" colspan="3">Seguros de Personas</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="td_0_1" rowspan="2">Total general</td>
          </tr>
```

I have tried as below but not able to get solution

```
 var count=0;
        $('table#sheet_0 td').each(function(){
            var td= $('td[colspan]').attr('colspan');
            if(td>0){
                var tdSelect=$('td[colspan]')[count];
                alert('hi' + tdSelect);
                var tdVal=tdSelect.val();
                alert(tdVal);
                for(var j = 0;j<td;j++){
                    $('<td>').append.val(tdVal).append('</td>');
                }
                count++;
            }else{

            }
        });
```

I need to produce td according to the colspan value with the same td value.

Help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Won't your loop inadvertently pick up new td's created on the fly?

Comment: what is the possible way to pick advertently, because I am new to Jquery.

Comment: I could be wrong, maybe someone can correct me here, but if you're adding new TD elements with `append` the loop you have `$('table#sheet_0 td').each(function(){`may loop through those too.

Comment: Also I notice you tag `<input type="checkbox" id="selectall" class="dt-checkboxes" value="">` is in between a TR and TD element. This code should sit inside a TD or TH when inside table code.

Comment: Yeah great point actually that check box is for whole row, Never mind about checkbox. For example, instead of <td class="td_0_1" colspan="3">Seguros de Personas</td> , I need [colspan="3"] 3 TD's to be generated

Comment: You need to review how append works.  You append nodes/elements, not html.  So `$("<td>").appendTo(` will already include the `<td>` *and* the `</td>`.  You should never append `</td>`.

Comment: Yeah could you help me by giving the code of it, But the values are not getting correctly since I have done the previous code. Kindly give me the solution

Comment: @ShankaraNethranS.N Please check below answer to get it done with JQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `colspan` from `td` then create `clone` element to that td and from clone remove `colspan` attribute.

Now `insert` new `td` and remove original `td` from table.

below is modification to your code.

```js
var count = 0;
$('table td').each(function() {
  var td = $(this).attr('colspan');
  if (td > 0) {
    var tdVal = $(this).html();
    for (var j = 0; j < td; j++) {
      var newTd = $(this).clone();
      newTd.removeAttr('colspan');
      newTd.html(tdVal);
      $(this).after(newTd);
    }
    $(this).remove();
    count++;
  } else {

  }
});
```

```css
.td_0_1,
{
  width: 30px;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr style="height:15.0pt;">
    <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="td_0_2" colspan="3">Seguros Generales</td>
    <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="td_0_1" colspan="3">Seguros de Personas</td>
    <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="td_0_1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="td_0_1" rowspan="2">Total general</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you got the solution, So it will be working dynamically ? so when ever table comes dynamically